# react-admin date input component not displaying correctly when view in mobile device

Tags: mobile, datepicker, react-admin

Do you all have a workaround for the date input component of react-admin?
(https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DateInput.html)

It seems that when the date input component is view in mobile device, the width will be cut off.

[Cut off Date Input Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCUJS.png)

To reproduce, simply navigate to https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/commands using your mobile device (e.g. iphone), then select the filter button, follow by Passed Since

You will realised the width is cut off. This is from react-admin demo page so it's probably a framework issue waiting to be fixed. However do you guys have any workaround while waiting for the fix?

However if you view it from chrome and emulate it using developer tool, you can see the expected behavior

[Expected behavior when View in Chrome emulating iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRvo.png)

Additionally if you select a date and rotate the iphone to landscape and rotate it back to portrait, amazingly the display is also good

[Expected behavior after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1N5m.png)

Comment: Could reproduce on my iPhone but not on desktop emulating mobile device, like you said. This could even be a bug with Safari mobile or webkit, because as soon as you click on the date input it moves to the correct position. Have you tried manually increasing the minWidth with the `sx` prop?

Comment: More info and a possible workaround are available in the GitHub issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/9215